# Spring RestTemplate - HttpClientErrorException.getResponseBodyAsString() returns unparseable value

Tags: spring, resttemplate

I am using Spring [RestTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) and having issue while catching an `HttpClientErrorException` with `postForEntity()`. The Exception's `getResponseBodyAsString()` method gets some random characters in the `String` value.

```java
try{
    HttpEntity<Object> reqEntity = new HttpEntity<Object>(objPayload, headers);
    ResponseEntity<Object> resEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, reqEntity, Object.class);
} catch(HttpStatusCodeException he) {
    log.error("Exception Status: {} -  {}", he.getStatusCode(), he.getStatusText());
    log.error("Exception - header {} ", he.getResponseHeaders());
    log.error("\n Exception - message  {} ", he.getResponseBodyAsString());
}
```

Exception message:

```
2024-02-01 14:48:28.801 ERROR [http-nio-8888-exec-2][APIController:318] Exception Status: 400 BAD_REQUEST -  Bad Request
<br/>
2024-02-01 14:48:28.802 ERROR [http-nio-8888-exec-2][APIController:319] Exception - header : [X-API-Mode:"Sandbox", Content-Encoding:"gzip", Content-Type:"application/json", Content-Length:"192", Server:"server-Gateway", Date:"Thu, 01 Feb 2024 19:48:28 GMT", Connection:"close", Server-Timing:"cdn-cache; desc=MISS", "edge; dur=25", "origin; dur=753", "ak_p; desc="1706816908113_1611090436_118439255_77820_5277_40_0_-";dur=1"]
```

The returned `String` with the strange characters:

```
2024-02-01 14:48:28.802 ERROR [http-nio-8888-exec-2][APIController:320] 
Exception - message    �       ��
        �@F_�2��ҝd� �hQ���\k�f`�&��������F�m@��Y�E!��-a�m�4Y��<�]��jݩ��3���A�Q(�i
        ˪:�6��Rֱ<^�ZV����1+�'���w-#Ӳ�n0V��p�Ͳq����wg,�ǀ���u   ��I�  `À/�c����$u^�
```

Making a request to the same endpoint using Postman I can't reproduce the issue:

```json
{
    "transactionId": "063dfe4c-07c3-4dc1-b495-e0ae41520",
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": "INVALID.INPUT.EXCEPTION",
            "message": "Invalid field value"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hi dear @Mayur - may I ask you the Spring Boot / Framework version you're using? Also, is it possible to share the full method of the endpoint you're referring in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Content-Encoding` in the log says `gzip` which means the API you are calling is returning a response compressed in gzip format, which Postman can decompress and display as JSON. However the default `RestTemplate` lacks the ability to decompress JSON, hence the strange characters in the log. You can customize the `RestTemplate` bean to internally use `Apache HttpClient`, which can handle gzip compressed responses.

**Bean definition:**

```java
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(
                HttpClientBuilder.create().build()
        );
        RestTemplate restTemplate = restTemplateBuilder.build();
        restTemplate.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);

        return restTemplate;
    }
}
```

**Additional dependency:**

```
implementation group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents.client5', name: 'httpclient5', version: '5.3.1'
```